# Breakpoint not hit in EF Core IEntityTypeConfiguration class on add-migration in PackageManagerConsole

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I am doing some discovery in a small test project and am trying to have a breakpoint hit in the configuration definition class.

```
public class TripExpenseComparisonEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TripExpenseComparison>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TripExpenseComparison> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id)
             .HasName("PK_TravelExpense");

        builder.OwnsOne(vo => vo.BudgetedTripExpense, exp =>
        {
            var x = from p in exp.GetType().GetProperties() where p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) select p;

            exp.Property(u => u.AllowNegatives)
                .IsRequired();

            exp.Ignore(u => u.TotalExpenses);

        });
       ... rest removed
```

When I run Add-Migration from the package manager console, in the DataAccess project, it runs the entire migration (correctly) EXCEPT it doesn't hit the breakpoint set on this line

```
>exp.Property(u => u.AllowNegatives)
        .IsRequired();
```

Do breakpoints not function in this type of class? Or do they not get hit during an add-migration event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this line `Debugger.Launch();` before the required place. It launches and attaches a debugger to the process.

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=net-5.0).

Another option you run the migration using `DbMigrator` through code and debug.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `Database.Migrate();` call in your `Startup.cs` then the breakpoint should be getting hit.

If you do and it still isn't, make sure you are applying the configurations in your DbContext class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext)));
}
```

*Where `MyDbContext` is the name of this class or a class in the same assembly as your `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` configurations.*